Ring of functions determines algebraic set
I'm studying some commutative algebra and the following problem was left as an exercise for the students:

If $A \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ and $B \subset \mathbb{C}^m$ are algebraic sets and $\mathcal{O}_A$ and $\mathcal{O}_B$ are their respective ring of algebraic functions, then $A$ and $B$ are isomorphic if, and only if, $\mathcal{O}_A$ and $\mathcal{O}_B$ are isomorphic.

Here, a morphism $A \to B$ is simply the restriction of a polynomial map $\mathbb{C}^n \to \mathbb{C}^m$ that, when restricted to $A$, has image lying in $B$. An isomorphism is a bijective morphism such that its inverse is also a morphism.
The "only if" part is not a problem: if $\phi \colon A \to B$ is an isomorphism, then the map $\mathcal{O}_B \to \mathcal{O}_A$ given by $f \mapsto f \circ \phi$ is a ring isomorphism (with inverse given by $g \mapsto g \circ \phi^{-1}$). What can I do about de converse?
I've tried using the isomorphisms \begin{equation}
\mathcal{O}_* \to \frac{\mathbb{C}[x_1, \dots, x_n]}{I(*)}
\end{equation} (here, $I(*) = \{f \in \mathbb{C}[x_1, \dots, x_n] \mid f(x) = 0, \forall x \in *\}$) to define the map: if $\psi \colon \frac{\mathbb{C}[y_1, \dots, y_n]}{I(A)} \to \frac{\mathbb{C}[x_1, \dots, x_m]}{I(B)}$ is an isomorphism, take $p_i$ as a representative of $\psi([y_i])$. Then, define the map $\phi \colon B \to A$ as $\phi = (p_1, \dots, p_n)$. I'm having trouble proving that it is indeed a isomorphism between algebraic sets, and I don't really know that it is. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

How do you define an isomorphism of algebraic sets?

@ZhenLin good question, I'll edit my post so it is easier to see

@ZhenLin edited

See proposition I.3.5 of Algebraic Geometry, Hartshorne.
Suppose you have the isomorphism
$$\psi : \frac {\mathbb{C}[y_{1},\ldots,y_{m}]}{I(B)} \rightarrow \frac {\mathbb{C}[x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}]}{I(A)}  $$
and $p_{i}=\psi([y_{i}])$ for $i=1,\ldots,m$ (following your notations, I've only switched A and B). Then you consider the map
$$\phi: A \rightarrow B$$
defined as $\phi (a)=(p_{1}(a),\ldots,p_{m}(a)) \in \mathbb{C}^{n}$. This is actually an element in $B$. Indeed $B=Z(I(B))$, so that an element $b$ is in $B$ if and only if for all  $f \in I(B)$ you have $f(b)=0$. So you have to prove that for all $a \in A$ and $f \in I(B)$ you have $f(\phi (a))=0$.
Indeed $$f(\phi(a))=f(p_{1}(a),\ldots,p_{m}(a))=f(\psi([y_{1}]),\ldots,\psi([y_{m}]))(a)=\psi(f([y_{1}],\ldots,[y_{m}]))(a)=0.$$
In order to prove that is is a morphism of algebraic sets you have to use the following (Hartshorne, I.3.6):
Lemma 3.6
Let $X$ be any variety, and let $Y \subseteq \mathbb{A}^{n}$ be an affine variety. A map of sets $\psi:X \rightarrow Y$ is a morphism if and only if $x_{i} \circ \psi$ is a regular function on $X$ for each $i$, where $x_{1},\ldots, x_{n}$ are coordinate functions on $\mathbb{A}^{n}.$
In this case if you compose $y_{i} \circ \phi (a)=p_{i}(a)$ given by polynomials. In order to see that this is an isomorphism you can check that you have an explicit inverse function, using the inverse of $\psi$.

Hi! First, thank you for your answer. I have a couple of questions: first, I don't understand what you mean by $p_i = \psi([y_i])$. The image of $\psi$ is in a set of classes, so we need to take $p_i$ as a representative of $\psi([y_i])$, so that $\psi([y_i]) = [p_i]$. I'm pointing this out because while proving that $\phi$ is well-defined, you take $f(p_1(a), ..., p_m(a)) = f(\psi([y_i]), ..., \psi([y_m]))(a)$, which isn't right, since $p_i \neq \psi([y_i])$. Also, what does it mean to apply $f$ to equivalence classes?

Moreover, why do I need to worry about proving that $\phi$ is a morphism? Once it is well-defined, it is a morphism by definition, since it is given by a polynomial map (each $p_i$ is a polynomial, by definition).

First, by $p_{i}$ in my notation I was already considering the class of $p_{i}$, sorry for not having specified that. We can use your notation and call it $[p_{i}]$. Then when you apply $f$, it just means you apply this to a representative of the class, and it make sense becasue $f$ is just a polynomial in $m$ variables and you apply all the stuff in a point. For the worrying about proving it is an isomorphism, you right here you just have polynomials, indeed in the answer I pointed out that in this case the use of the Lemma is trivial, since the compositions are just polynomials.

Why do $\psi$ and $f$ commute in your proof of $f(\phi(a)) = 0$?

That is because $\psi$ is a ring homomorphism and $f$ is just a polynomial. Hence you just have to commute with sums and products.

Yeah, but it does not necessarily preserves scalars. Morphisms comute with polynomials in $\mathbb{Q}[x_1, \dots, x_n]$, since every ring morphism preserves the prime field, but it may be that $\psi$ changes the coefficients of $f$.

$\psi$ is an isomorphism of $\mathbb{C}$-algebras. By definition it preserves the field $\mathbb{C}$, hence preserves scalars.

Oh, I am supposed to use morphisms of algebras? The problem was stated withou saying how the ring of functions are isomorphic. With only them being ring-isomorphic the result fails?
